# Add functional component dynamical in react with out using class component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a list of skills that are supposed to build in UI and I didn't have any problem in this step.
**But** when I add a new item to the list by writing it in input and clicking on a button to add it, the console sends a massage to tell: skills is not iterable.

this is a code in the App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import Skills from './Components/Details'
import React,{useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [numApp,reNumApp] = useState(0)
  const [skill,reSkill] = useState('')
  const [skills,reSkills] = useState(['HTML'])
  
  const addSkill = (value)=>{
    let newList = skills.push(value);
    reSkills(newList);
    console.log(skills);
     
  }

  
  console.log(skills)
  return(
    <>
      <h1>Num Of applecation:{numApp}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>reNumApp(numApp + 1)}>Other Application</button>
      <hr/>
      <input type='text' value={skill} onChange={(e)=>reSkill(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={()=>{addSkill(skill)}}>Add</button>
      <Skills skills = {skills}/>

    </>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

And this is the code in the Details file:

```
import React,{useState,Fragment} from 'react';

function Skill({key,value})
{
  const  [count,reCount] = useState(0)
  return(
    <>
      <span><p key={key}>{value} : {count}</p></span>
      <button onClick={()=>reCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
    
  )
}

function Skills({skills}) {
  return(

    <Fragment>
      {
        [...skills].map((v,i)=>{return <Skill key={i} value={v}/>})
      }
    </Fragment>
  )
  
}


export default Skills
```

I need to know how can I solve this problem without using the class component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to push on the current state, so change this:

```
let newList = skills.push(value);
reSkills(newList);
```

to this:

```
reSkills([...skills, value]);
```

Comment: That's an easy and helpful solution, It's done correctly thanks.